# SQL Join on Column with Match or Latest Time

Tags: sql, join, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I've been struggling on this problem for a while now and a bit out of my depth with SQL to solve this. I'll give a bit of a summary of what my dataset looks like and what I am trying to achieve.

Just as a side note, I will be running this SQL script on the Microsoft Azure DataBricks platform.

I have three tables which represent timeline data. These are Cycle, Activity and Delay. I am looking to combine all three of the tables.

The Cycle and Activity tables are related to each other with the CYCLE_OID column used to join them.

The Delay timeline is a subset of the Activity timeline but only has entries that align between the start and end of delay activities and there is no relationship between the two columns which can be directly joined.

An example of some mock data in the tables (I have just kept the relevant columns) is below:

**Cycle:**

| STARTTIME_UTC | ENDTIME_UTC | ACTIVITY_TYPE | MACHINE | CYCLE_OID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-13T08:23:48 | 2023-03-13T09:53:26 | Working | MX01 | 165803 |
| 2023-03-13T09:53:26 | 2023-03-13T11:24:10 | Delay | MX01 | 165973 |

**Activity Table:**

| START_TIME_UTC | END_TIME_UTC | ACTIVITY_TYPE | MACHINE | CYCLE_OID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-13T08:23:48 | 2023-03-13T09:01:12 | Delay | MX01 | 165803 |
| 2023-03-13T09:01:12 | 2023-03-13T09:37:49 | Working | MX01 | 165803 |
| 2023-03-13T09:37:49 | 2023-03-13T09:53:26 | Delay | MX01 | 165803 |
| 2023-03-13T09:53:26 | 2023-03-13T10:27:03 | Delay | MX01 | 165973 |
| 2023-03-13T10:27:03 | 2023-03-13T11:03:52 | Working | MX01 | 165973 |
| 2023-03-13T11:03:52 | 2023-03-13T11:24:10 | Delay | MX01 | 165973 |

**Delay Table:**

| START_UTC | END_UTC | DELAY_CODE | MACHINE | DELAY_OID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-13T08:23:48 | 2023-03-13T08:46:23 | Refuel | MX01 | 1673 |
| 2023-03-13T08:46:23 | 2023-03-13T09:01:12 | Water Fill | MX01 | 1678 |
| 2023-03-13T09:53:26 | 2023-03-13T10:27:03 | Comms Loss | MX01 | 1692 |
| 2023-03-13T11:03:52 | 2023-03-13T11:24:10 | Emergency | MX01 | 1704 |

The final table that I am looking to create is:

**Result Table:**

| START | END | ACTIVITY | DELAY_CODE | MACHINE | DELAY_OID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-13T08:23:48 | 2023-03-13T08:46:23 | Delay | Refuel | MX01 | 1673 |
| 2023-03-13T08:46:23 | 2023-03-13T09:01:12 | Delay | Water Fill | MX01 | 1678 |
| 2023-03-13T09:01:12 | 2023-03-13T09:37:49 | Working | NULL | MX01 | NULL |
| 2023-03-13T09:37:49 | 2023-03-13T09:53:26 | Delay | Comms Loss | MX01 | 1692 |
| 2023-03-13T09:53:26 | 2023-03-13T10:27:03 | Delay | Comms Loss | MX01 | 1692 |
| 2023-03-13T10:27:03 | 2023-03-13T11:03:52 | Working | NULL | MX01 | NULL |
| 2023-03-13T11:03:52 | 2023-03-13T11:24:10 | Delay | Emergency | MX01 | 1704 |

Below is a basic outline of the tables in a timeline format.

[image]

Some things to note:

- As you can see, the delays with DELAY_OID of 1673 and 1678 both sit within the first delay activity from the Activity table. But there can be multiple activities (and hence delays) within a single CYCLE_OID.
- A single delay can also span across multiple cycles and activities such as the delay with DELAY_OID = 1692.

What I have been trying to do is join the Delay table to the Activity and Cycle tables through a conditional join where either:

1. START_TIME_UTC = START_UTC

OR

2. START_UTC = the previous START_TIME_UTC and END_UTC is equal to or before the corresponding END_TIME_UTC value.

This however does not account for breaking delays across the multiple cycles or activities.

Below is an example of what I have tried to do so far:

```
SELECT * FROM

CYCLE AS C
LEFT JOIN
Activity AS A
ON C.STARTTIME_UTC = A.START_TIME_UTC
LEFT JOIN
Delay AS D
ON A.MACHINE = D.MACHINE AND 
(A.START_TIME_UTC = D.START_UTC OR
(A.START_TIME_UTC < D.START_UTC AND A.END_TIME_UTC >= D.END_UTC)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Precise matching through timestamps is almost never fully successful (as there can be tiny differences in the actual stored timestamp -vs- what you see depicted on screen). With this in mind I suggest this:

```
SELECT 
    a.START_TIME_UTC START
  , a.END_TIME_UTC END
  , a.ACTIVITY_TYPE ACTIVITY
  , d.DELAY_CODE
  , d.MACHINE
  , d.DELAY_OID
FROM CYCLE AS C
LEFT JOIN Activity AS A ON C.CYCLE_OID = A.CYCLE_OID
LEFT JOIN DELAY AS D ON A.MACHINE = D.MACHINE
    AND D.START_UTC BETWEEN A.START_TIME_UTC AND A.END_TIME_UTC
    AND a.ACTIVITY_TYPE <> 'Working'
ORDER BY 
    a.START_TIME_UTC
  , a.END_TIME_UTC
```

| start | end | activity | delay_code | machine | delay_oid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-13 08:23:48 | 2023-03-13 09:01:12 | Delay | Refuel | MX01 | 1673 |
| 2023-03-13 08:23:48 | 2023-03-13 09:01:12 | Delay | Water Fill | MX01 | 1678 |
| 2023-03-13 09:01:12 | 2023-03-13 09:37:49 | Working | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2023-03-13 09:37:49 | 2023-03-13 09:53:26 | Delay | Comms Loss | MX01 | 1692 |
| 2023-03-13 09:53:26 | 2023-03-13 10:27:03 | Delay | Comms Loss | MX01 | 1692 |
| 2023-03-13 10:27:03 | 2023-03-13 11:03:52 | Working | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2023-03-13 11:03:52 | 2023-03-13 11:24:10 | Delay | Emergency | MX01 | 1704 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4q89-a_J)